# Is there a way to make docker config editable from inside a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have to start each instance of my application as a separate Docker service. The base image is the same but the configuration file is different for each instance. Now, the problem is my application makes some changes to the configuration file. And I want the configuration changes to persist so that when my application restarts (as docker service), it uses the updated configuration.

I am able to use the config file as a mount point using `docker config`. But the problem is no matter what mode (`rwx`) I give, I am not able to update the config file from inside the container. The mounted config is always **Read-only file system**.

#### 1. How do I make the changes to the config file from docker container?

#### 2. How do I make the updated config file persist outside the container, so that on service restart, the updated configuration is used?

I did the following to decouple config file from the image/container:

```
docker config create my-config config.txt
docker service create \
--name redis \
--config src=my-config,target=/config.txt,mode=0660 \
redis:alpine
docker container exec -ti <containerId> /bin/sh
```

The config file is mounted at `/config.txt` but I am not able to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The config will be read only by design. But you can copy this to another file inside your container as part of an entrypoint script defined in your image.

```
docker config create my-config config.txt
docker service create \
--name redis \
--config src=my-config,target=/config.orig,mode=0660 \
username/redis:custom
```

The entrypoint script would include the following:

```
if [ ! -f /config.txt -a -f /config.orig ];
  cp /config.orig /config.txt
fi
# skipping the typical exec command here since redis has its own entrypoint
# exec "$@" # run the CMD as pid 1
exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Your Dockerfile to build that image would look like:

```
FROM redis:alpine
COPY /entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And you'd build that with:

```
docker build -t username/redis:custom .
```

Comment: Making a copy of the mounted config file is a decent approach. But how do I make the config changes to persist, so that if I restart my service I have an updated config file?

Comment: Also, my excel file is an excel sheet

Comment: @risabhRizz If you want persistence, that's a volume, you no longer want a centrally managed config. I don't understand the excel file reference, this is about a docker config for a redis image.

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm configs are read-only, not only from inside the container but also from the outside. to update the config of your service you must create a new config as explained in the [docker swarm config docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#example-rotate-a-config)

**How do I update the config of my service?**
 You need to to copy the config, edit it, save it with new name, and then update the service

```sh
# Get the config from docker to file
docker config inspect --pretty my-config | tail -n +6 > conf-file 
# Edit conf-file as needed here
...
# Save it with new name
docker config create my-config-v2 conf-file
# Update the service
docker service update \
  --config-rm my-config \
  --config-add source=my-config-v2,target=/config.txt \
  redis:alpine
```

**How do I update the config from inside the container?**
For this you'll need to have access to docker from inside the container. you can do so by mounting the docker executable and the docker sock to the container:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
               -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
       ubuntu bash
```